# Change Background and text color of Time Picker button in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, timepicker

I'm new to flutter and want to implement a Time Picker, However I'm not able to change the background of `cancel` and `ok` buttons.

Expected :

[image: Expected Color of ok and Cancel button]

I'm using the below code for button theme

```
textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Color(0xFF2B2B2B),
    side: BorderSide(
     width: 1.5,
     color: Color(0xFFC5C5C5),),
     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(18, 12, 18, 12),
     elevation: 1,
  ),
```

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the property `backgroundColor` of your `ButtonStyle`:

### Code sample

```dart
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red, // Use this
        side: const BorderSide(
          width: 1.5,
          color: Color(0xFFC5C5C5),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  // ...
)
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=63cb1746ed3f519948584d47d1ae5268)

### Screenshot

[image]

Comment: but the background color of buttons is still same

Comment: @amanbisht39 Okay so what you want is having 2 different button style for `cancel` and `ok`. This might need to re-implement `TimePickerDialog` as you don't have access to those properties.